# When do I get my Gems back?

Tags: dragonvale

In sheer Generosity I enjoy handing out Gems to my friends. However I've noticed that when I receive my Gems for the day I can't always share my daily gems with friends I've shared with yesterday.

When does this timer reset? This inability to share is a crime against fabulosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Dragonvale wikia FAQ: [here](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ).

> Q: Is there any other ways to get gems besides paying for them?
>
> A: Yes, A friend may gift you a gem every 24 hours. Each player is given 3 gems to gift daily, so forming a group of four with three other active players can guarantee that each day you receive three gems to use.This can be changed if you have a Dragonsai Gem Tree which you can use to send 6 gems to gift instead of 3. A site has been setup to help organize the creation of gifting teams at http://dragonvale.angells.com/teams.

Comment: huh, the clock must be separate from getting the gems back

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have more than 3 friends to enable testing.  I have observed that I have "3 Gifts Available to Give Today!" before I can actually press the "Free Gift" button.  I don't know why that is exactly, maybe a bug.

Comment: The count definately resets at a certain time, what I'm saying is I think the Free Gift only un-greys-out 24 hours after you've gifted to that person. BTW there's at least 4 of us in chat that you can friend in game center!

Comment: Sometimes **[force closing DragonVale](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5137)** can cause the `Free Gift` button to work again, although this it is likely that the 24 hours have past and the DragonVale has just not updated. If you are expecting the `Free Gift` buttons to be active, try `Force Closing` the app, it might help.